# TypeScriptでListやMap等のコレクションを扱うライブラリはありますか？

Tags: typescript

TypescriptでListやMapなどのコレクションを簡単に扱えるライブラリはありますか？
イメージとしては、JavaのGuavaのようなライブラリが理想ですが、
java.util.Collection　に相当する程度でも問題ありません。

Comment: Listに関しては標準のArrayで様々な操作がサポートされています https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: なるほど。Javascript標準でいろいろついているわけですね。勉強になりました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

標準のArrayでは機能不足でしたら[Closure Library](https://github.com/google/closure-library)と[closure-library.d.ts](https://github.com/teppeis/closure-library.d.ts)を使うという方法もあります。

```
/// <reference path="closure-library.d.ts/all.d.ts" />

goog.require('goog.structs.Map');

var m = new goog.structs.Map('a', 1, 'b', 2);
console.log(m.get('a'));
console.log(m.containsKey('b'));
console.log(m.containsKey('c'));
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！試してみます。